# Problema al ejecutar un script en Bash enlazado con otro script que crea un archivo

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell, awk

Primero de todo, gracias por adelantado.
Soy nuevo en BASH y necesitaría ayuda con un par de scripts que he creado. Estoy con un dataset descargado de GITHUB sobre casos Covid por países. Por más que le he dado vueltas no soy capaz de conseguir que se me ejecute correctamente un script 'B' que se ejecuta después de otro script 'A' que a su vez crea un archivo csv.

Comparto el código que estoy utilizando.

Script 'A.sh' (seguro que el código es muy mejorable)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Transponemos las fechas que están estructuradas en columnas a filas.
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","};NR==1{n = split($0,a); print "Country,date,value"; next};{for(i=2;i<NF;i++) print $1,a[i],$i}' $HOME/casos_covid.csv |

# Realizamos un Groupby dado que hay países que en el dataset original tenían un detalle de casos de covid por provincias/regiones. 

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","};NR==1{print;next};{a[$1","$2]+=$3};END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' > $HOME/data.csv
```

Script 'B.sh' que se enlaza a través de un script principal que ejecuta ambos scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Realiza un cruce (Vlookup) entre el fichero paises y el dataset data.csv
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","};FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next};NR>1{if($1 in a){print $2,$3,a[$1]}}' $HOME/paises_ok.csv $HOME/data.csv |

# Modificamos la estructura del dataset antes de realizar el siguiente paso del script.
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","};{print $3,$1,$2}' |

# Reliza un groupby por continente, de esta forma sumamos los casos a nivel de contiente.
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","};NR==1{print;next};{a[$1","$2]+=$3};END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' > casos_continentes.csv
```

Adjunto también el script principal.sh que he creado.

```
#!/bin/bash
source $HOME/A.sh |
source $HOME/B.sh
```

La cuestión es que no soy capaz de hacer que funcione el primer comando 'awk' del script B.sh donde realizo un Vlookup con otro archivo que contiene una relación de países y continentes. Lo he probado por activa y por pasiva pero no hay forma y el resultado que obtengo es siempre el mismo, se genera el archivo data.csv (script A) pero luego el código del script B.sh se ejecuta hasta al final y genera el fichero 'casos_contiente.csv' pero me lo genera vacío. Es como que no lee el fichero data.csv generado en el script A.sh.

No lo acabo de entender ya que el procesamiento es secuencial y entiendo que debería leer el archivo data.csv.

Os agradecería enormemente vuestra ayuda para ver si me podéis echar un cable y saber en qué me estoy equivocando.

Un saludo,

Comment: necesitamos un [mcve] para poder replicar el problema y ayudarte. Dale a [edit] y comparte un ejemplo representativo